# iText, PageSize A4 - units

Tags: java, itext

I'm creating document in iText. I need custom width however when it's smaller than A4 standard width, it should be set to A4 standard width.

So I got:

```
float pageWidth = columns.size() * 100;
if (pageWidth < PageSize.A4.getWidth()) {
       pageWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
}
table.setTotalWidth(pageWidth);
```

And it's not working, probably because `pageWidth` and `PageSize.A4.getWidth()` got different units. 
When I debugged this, I got `900.0` value in `pageWidth` and `PageSize.A4.getWidth()` returns `595.0`
So what do I need to change to get same units for comparison?

Comment: What is `columns`? In particular what is `columns.size ()` and why do you multiply it with `100`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

900 is not lower than 595, so `pageWidth<PageSize.A4.getWidth()` is not true, and this is never executed: `pageWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth();`

The value of `pageWidth` never changes. You have 9 colums. You multiply with 100 and that results in 900. 900 is bigger than 595, so `pageWidth` remains 900.

I think you want the opposite of what you're asking:

```
float pageWidth = columns.size()*100;
if(pageWidth > PageSize.A4.getWidth()){
   pageWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
 }
table.setTotalWidth(pageWidth);
```

Now, when `pageWidth` doesn't fit he page, it will be reduced to 595.

I think you made a logical error that is totally unrelated to iText.